# Regex only inside multiline match

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I have an old app that generates something like:

```
USERLIST (
    "jasonr"
    "jameso"
    "tommyx"
)
ROLELIST (
    "op"
    "admin"
    "ro"
)
```

I need some form of regex that changes ONLY the `USERLIST` section to `USERLIST("jasonr", "jameso", "tommyx")` and the rest of the text remain intact:

```
USERLIST("jasonr", "jameso", "tommyx")
ROLELIST (
    "op"
    "admin"
    "ro"
)
```

In addition to the multiline issue, I don't know how to handle the replacement in only part of the string. I've tried perl (`-0pe`) and sed, can't find a solution. I don't want to write an app to do this, surely there is a way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
perl -0777 -wpe'
    s{USERLIST\s*\(\K ([^)]+) }{ join ", ", $1 =~ /("[^"]+")/g }ex' file
```

Prints the desired output on the shown input file.  Broken over lines for easier view.

With [`-0777` switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-0%5Boctal/hexadecimal%5D) the whole file is read at once into a string ("slurped") and is thus in `$_`. With `/x` modifier literal spaces in the pattern are ignored so can be used for readability.

Explanation

- Capture what follows `USERLIST (`, up to the first closing parenthesis. This assumes no such paren inside `USERLIST( ... )`. With [`\K` lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#%5CK) all matches prior to it stay (are not "consumed" out of the string) and are excluded from `$&`, so we don't have to re-enter them in the replacement side
- The replacement side is evaluated as code, courtesy of `/e` modifier.  In it we capture all double-quoted substrings from the initial `$1` capture (assuming no nested quotes) and join that list by `,` . The obtained string is then used for the replacement for what was in the parentheses following `USERLIST`

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples in GNU `awk` please try following `awk` code.

```bash
awk -v RS='(^|\n)USERLIST \\(\n[^)]*\\)\n' '
RT{
  sub(/[[:space:]]+\(\n[[:space:]]+/,"(",RT)
  sub(/[[:space:]]*\n\)\n/,")",RT)
  gsub(/"\n +"/,"\", \"",RT)
  print RT
}
END{
  printf("%s",$0)
}
'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Setting `RS`(record separator) as `(^|\n)USERLIST \\(\n[^)]*\\)\n` for all lines of Input_file. Then in main program checking condition if RT is NOT NULL then substituting `[[:space:]]+\(\n[[:space:]]+` with `"("` and then substituting `[[:space:]]*\n\)\n` with `)` and then substituting `"\n +"` with `\"` finally printing its value. Then in this program's END block printing line's value in `printf` function to get rest of the values.

Output will be as follows:

```
USERLIST("jasonr", "jameso", "tommyx")
ROLELIST (
    "op"
    "admin"
    "ro"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/USERLIST/{:a;N;/^)$/M!ba;s/(\n\s*/(/;s/\n)/)/;s/\n\s*/, /g}' file
```

If a line contains `USERLIST`, gather up the list and format as required.